# Spring Dependency Injection Scenario

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, scenarios

I am have a confusion on how to go about with above scenario in Spring (dependency injection context)

```
class Login {
   String username;
   String password;
   UserAuthService userAuth;

   /* 
      assume getter and setter 
      methods for above private
      properties here
   */

}
```

UserAuthService is a interface which has a  boolean method validate(String username , String password);

It is implemented by  BasicAuthService, LDAPAuthService, MockBasicAuthService, MockLDAPAuthService;
Also Assume that BasicAuthServie has a property serverAddress , as string which has the IP address of authentication server,
same with LDAPAuthService.

Context of my Question is Dependency Injection and Spring ,

I understood that based on beanconfig file Spring('s IOC) will inject one of the concrete implementation of 
UserAuthService.

1 . In beanconfig file we can only configure one  ref say ( )
    Scenario: Suppose in UI user has a dropdown to select  BasicAuth / LDAPAuth . User have selected LDAPAuth , how to deal with this case in spring ?
    since we have hardwired  ref="beanIdBasicAuthService" in beanconfig file). Is there a way to dynamicaly change the ref ?

2 . Little more complex ( assume IT admin or so) , UI is now providing option to select the address of the authentication server (which is a property in the Basic/LDAP Auth Service Class)
    Again in beanconfig file we would have hardwired the properties. How to go about dynamicaly changing it in spring ? (other than explicitly getting the injected bean and calling setterMethod)

These scenarios are a bit confusing to me. Can someone please explain this ?

Answer (score 0):

Answer to both questions: inject a factory class instead.
E.g. in your example:

```
class Login {
   String username;
   String password;
   UserAuthServiceFactory userAuthFactory;

   /* 
      assume getter and setter 
      methods for above private
      properties here
   */
}

class UserAuthServiceFactory {
     UserAuthService createUserAuth(String type, String remoteHost, ...) {...}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring offers some white magic, but you are really requiring black magic here :-).

More seriously, you are right on one part: Spring can only configure a bean at bean creation time **and only if it creates the bean**. BTW, there is also the question of the scope: a Singleton bean will only be created once and same object will be used throughout the application, whereas with bean scope, a new object will be constructed when it is requested from the application context.

But, once you have a bean, you are free to use it and change values that were initialized by Spring.

That is simply the way to go for second question: inject the AuthService(s) in the UI, and simply change the server address through the UI (with a bit of synchronization...): the new address will be used from that moment.

For the first question, I would first say that is is uncommon to inject an authentication service in a class like your `Login` class. First it forces you to create any `Login` object through a request to the application context which unnecessarily ties your application to Spring classes. IMHO a better design would be to have a master authentication class injected with a container of concrete authentication objects, and delegating actual authentication to them. It is what Spring Security does with an AuthenticationManager that delegates actual authentication to AuthenticationProviders.